# jest-native toBeOnTheScreen

Tags: react-native, native-testing-library

Why would you ever need to use the `toBeOnTheScreen` matcher from jest-native. https://github.com/testing-library/jest-native#tobeonthescreen My understanding is in the example within the docs the `getByTestId` would simply error if the 'child' element wasn't present so then writing the expect seems unnecessary. I could understand if `queryByTestId` was used as this wouldn't cause the error.

```
const child = screen.getByTestId('child');
expect(child).toBeOnTheScreen();
```

Is it just to check if the element hasn't been removed between the time when you captured it and another point in the test? if so, the docs example seems a little misleading. What am I missing.